# save figure with subplots as a PDF

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am using the following code to convert my MATLAB figures into PDF as it does a great job removing the unnecessary margins and I can use it inside loops. However, when I have figures with subplots it doesn't work because the code uses only the current axis. I haven't been able to generalize the code in the way I want. Appreciate any help.

```
ax = gca;
set(ax,'fontname','Times New Roman','fontsize',12)
ti = get(ax,'TightInset');
set(ax,'Position',[ti(1) ti(2) 1-ti(3)-ti(1) 1-ti(4)-ti(2)]);
set(ax,'units','centimeters')
pos = get(ax,'Position');
ti = get(ax,'TightInset');
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits','centimeters');
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [pos(3)+ti(1)+ti(3) pos(4)+ti(2)+ti(4)]);
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual');
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition',[0 0 pos(3)+ti(1)+ti(3) pos(4)+ti(2)+ti(4)]);
saveas(gcf,['sample.pdf'])
```

Comment: `saveas(gcf)` is NOT working on only one axis, `gcf` is the whole figure.  The lines with `gca` are operating on a single axis, so you will need to repeat them for each subplot.  Also, the "removing unnecessary margins" logic isn't set up for subplots... remember that you can use `get` to read the values that Matlab created, and compare them to the ones the existing code sets up, to better understand the approach.

Comment: A possibly higher-quality approach would be to use `matlab2tikz` to turn your figure into something that gets processed through a program for high quality mathematical typesetting (LaTeX + TikZ is one of the best ones around).  TikZ has good subplot support.

Comment: @Ben: This code specifically expands the current axes to cover the whole figure. You cannot repeat this for each axes.

Comment: Instead of the code you post here, use [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig) (link goes to the File Exchange).

Comment: @CrisLuengo: setting fontname and fontsize can be simply repeated for each axis.  Margin removal needs to be changed to work in a subplot environment, but the problem isn't that you can't repeat things, it's that interior spacing and exterior margins need to be treated differently.  And `export_fig` is a good replacement for the final `saveas` function call, but it won't help much with optimizing the subplot layour.

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt `matlab2tikz` is really nice